# Encrypt on iSeries

Tags: encryption, ibm-midrange

What tools are available to encrypt or password-protect a file stored on the IFS?

*integrated file-system, accessible from Windows

Answer (score 2):

1. You could setup object security so only certain users can view the file.
2. There are encryption tools available for purchase. There is also some built-in APIs for encrypting.

Here are some resources to look into:

1. [Scenario: Key Management and File Encryption Using the Cryptographic Services APIs](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=/apis/qc3Scenario.htm)
2. [The Next Step in Security](http://www.ibmsystemsmag.com/i5/june04/administrator/8475p4.aspx)
3. [A Simple Encryption/Decryption Algorithm for Numbers](http://www.itjungle.com/fhg/fhg042705-story01.html)
4. [Cryptographic Services APIs](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=/apis/catcrypt.htm)

Most of these articles deal with encrypting data in a table, but the concepts should help you encrypt a file on the IFS.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could simply encrypt the file from a Windows box with [ccrypt](http://ccrypt.sourceforge.net/) or [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) (perhaps not what you are looking for). Both are free. As is [GnuPG](http://www.gnupg.org/) which has a windows port and is probably the best of the bunch.

Don't forget that iSeries with [PASE](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/systems/scope/i5os/index.jsp?topic=/rzalf/rzalfintro.htm) can run many AIX programs as is.

ccrypt for AIX could almost definitely be made to run on the iSeries and be called from QSH. And similarly for GnuPG for AIX; it could be run on the iSeries itself.

Answer (score 1):

There is [PkZIP](http://www.pkware.com/software-pkzip/iseries-file-compression) for the iSeries which can provide encryption.

You could also 'roll your own' encryption using [Java Cryptography](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html).

Answer (score 1):

We are currently using Arpeggio, which is free. We used to use PKZip, but were able to replace that tool with the free Arpeggio software. Seems to work well

Answer (score 0):

You can set the authority to the file so only users in one group have access to it.  I think its option 9 I don't have access to a iseries at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

You can pull a port of GnuPG from Scott Klement's website at : https://www.scottklement.com/gnupg/. We have been using it without issue for years.

Answer (score 0):

A lot has changed since this question was asked! IBM i now has extensive support for open source software in PASE. Several of the other answers here mention packages that IBM now provides for no cost as [RPMs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPM_Package_Manager), easily installable via yum (or the Access Client Solutions GUI, which includes a graphical front-end for yum). Here is just a sampling of IBM-packaged tools you could use for encryption of IFS files:

- [GnuPG](https://kadler.io/2020/07/15/jun-oss-updates.html#)
- [p7zip](https://kadler.io/2020/07/15/jun-oss-updates.html#) (POSIX version of 7-Zip, compatible with and mostly superior to PKZIP)
- Python, Node.js, and other programming languages, with access to various encryption libraries

Note that the [RPM-based packaging](https://ibmi-oss-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/yum/README.html) is only supported on IBM i 7.2 and above. (Some people have been able to get it working on [7.1](https://ibmi-oss-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/yum/README.html#ibm-i-7-1-install-instructions-experimental-not-supported), but this requires the right combination of PTFs and know-how.)

For those on older (and by now, far out of support) versions of IBM i and its predecessors, you may be able to use Scott Klement's ports of [GnuPG](https://www.scottklement.com/gnupg/) and [p7zip](https://www.scottklement.com/p7zip/), or Per Gummedal's [iSeriesPython](https://sourceforge.net/projects/iseriespython/).